# Regarding creating unmanaged package in salesforce

Tags: unmanaged-package

I am getting below error while creating package:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/signup-finish?email=rameshwari_wagh%40persistent.co.in&name=Rameshwari&token=ccd521e2-449b-461d-8f83-32d4e840aebb%3a5GuH89hp8hQB%2fgoiXUUeP6FrhV0%3d&sus=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fsalesforce.stackexchange.com%2f&authCode=0cdddf8643391654ad72ca3104269564bd449c0065a4e68ad410d11af91a47bb

please provide some solution on this.

Comment: Sorry Ignore previous message and sended link.

Comment: I am getting below error while uploading unmanaged package :          An unexpected error occurred when uploading your package. Please contact Salesforce Support and provide the following error code: 2036515993-134762 (-1907985851)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds obvious, but I would contact Salesfoce support for that.

In my previous experience, whenver this has happened (maybe with a different error code), it was an indicator that something was corrupted in the org where I was packaging from. Have you tried creating a new dev org, uploading all your metadata there and trying to create the package there?